# How to use dropdownlist selected value to refresh table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a method in my tasks_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end
```

and I use table to desplay `@tasks`

```
  <table>     
    <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Content</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
        <tr>
        <td><%= task.name %></td>
        <td><%= task.content %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %> 
    </tbody>   
  </table>
```

my dropdownlist

```
<%= f.label 'Task' %>: <%= f.select :locate_id, Locate.all.collect { |l| [ l.locate_name, l.id ] }, {:prompt => 'choose'}, :onchange => '$.get(#{/index})' %>
```

when dropdownlist selected, I hope this table can auto refresh(just refresh table) with selected values, with following method:

```
@tasks = Task.where('locate_id = ?', params[:task][:locate_id])
```

how can I do that? I search for this question, it seem's like to use `onchange` and `javascript` can do what I want, does someone can give me some tips, I am a totally rookie on javascript...
thanks.

I add  :'data-remote' => 'true',:'data-type' => 'HTML' to my `select`, and I get the right respond(my selected value to search) from server just like I enter the page, but the page does't refresh. what the problem?

```
Started GET "/tasks/new" for IP at 2015-08-10 10:24:15 +0800
Processing by TasksController#new as HTML
  Account Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  Locate Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `locates`.* FROM `locates`
  Account Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE (manager_id = 2)
  Beacon Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `beacons`.* FROM `beacons` WHERE (account_id = 2) AND (beacon_status < 3)
  Category Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/_form.html.erb (9.1ms)
  Rendered tasks/new.html.erb within layouts/application (9.9ms)
  Rendered common/_navbar.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered common/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 64ms (Views: 60.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)


Started GET "/tasks/new?task%5Blocate_id%5D=1" for IP at 2015-08-10 10:24:19 +0800
Processing by TasksController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"task"=>{"locate_id"=>"1"}}
  Account Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  Locate Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `locates`.* FROM `locates`
  Account Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE (manager_id = 2)
  Beacon Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `beacons`.* FROM `beacons` WHERE (account_id = 2) AND (beacon_status < 3) AND (locate_id = '1')
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/_form.html.erb (7.8ms)
  Rendered tasks/new.html.erb within layouts/application (14.5ms)
  Rendered common/_navbar.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered common/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 85ms (Views: 82.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the change event. When an options is selected from the dropdown, write an event handler to capture this event (see [this link](http://api.jquery.com/change/)). In the handler function, make an [Ajax request](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to your server. Ajax requests have a success handler, which is basically a function that executes when a request has been successfully completed. In this function, one of the parameters will be the data sent by the server and dynamically update the table as you like. You'll probably need a JSON API in your server for this. The standard HTML response will not do.

Comment: Vary thanks for your suggestion, but after a period time to read, I still can't get the point(this case has a little bit urgent, so I have not much time to read), I add some way which I tried, if you have time, please take a look.